# Finding the longest alphabetical order substring in a longer stringer

Tags: python-3.x

I have made a few attempts at writing this code but it isn't consistently solving the problem. Most often it will not output the first and last characters in the string. I am not sure where I am going wrong and I'm a bit lost at this point about what to do, can someone give me a bit of an explanation as to where the issue is with my code and how to fix it?

```
s = ' abcdekyuuhhoowhoiwv '
longS = ''
tempS = ''
for x in range(len(s)-1):
    if s[x] <= s[x+1]:
        longS += s[x+1]
        if len(longS) < len(tempS):
            tempS = longS
    else:
        tempS = s[x+1]
print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + str(longS))
```

Comment: what is expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Python is much easier if you can avoid using indexes in loops. It's designed to make that easy because indexes lend themselves to hard-to-see off-by-one errors. For example, in your code you never use `s[x]` so you always miss the first letter of the string.

One way to tackle this is to keep track of the last letter seen in a variable. Initialize that with the first letter and then iterate the rest. It then becomes pretty readable:

```
s = 'abcdekyuuhhoowhoiwv'

# initialize
last = s[0]
current = last
longest = last

# loop letters starting at the second
for letter in s[1:]:
    if letter >= last:
        current += letter    
    else:
        current = letter  
    if len(current) > len(longest):
        longest = current

    last = letter

print(longest)
# 'abcdeky'
```

Also, I didn't test for an empty string above, but you probably should if there's any chance of one.

Answer (score 0):

I am using dynamic programming. And also my solution outputs many solution if present.

```py
s = input()

a = [1]

for i in range(1,len(s)):
    if ord(s[i-1]) <= ord(s[i]):
        a.append(a[-1]+1)
    else:
        a.append(1)
m = max(a)
am = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == m]

for i in am:
    ans = ""
    for j in range(i,i-m,-1):
        ans = s[j] + ans
    print(ans)
```

### Testcases

**Input**

```sh
abcdekyuuhhoowhoiwv
```

**Output**

```sh
abcdeky
```

**Input**

```sh
abcdekabcdef
```

**Output**

```sh
abcdek
abcdef
```