# longest alphabetical substring not returning last index character

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python on my own and running into a few questions. Can anyone help me understand why this code doesn't append 'z' to the 'temp' or 'ls' variables? Thank you!

```
temp = ""
ls = ""

for i in range(len(s) - 1):
    if s[i] <= s[i+1]:
       temp += s[i]

    else:
        temp += s[i]
        if(len(temp) > len(ls)):
            ls = temp
        temp = ""
if len(temp) > len(ls):
    print ("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + str(temp))
else:
    print ("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + str(ls))
```

Comment: Can you give an example input/output?

Comment: I think the OP means, if `s = "abcdez"` then why is the longest substring `abcde`, without the `z`.
It's because the `for` loop has `-1` in the `range`.

Comment: It's much easier if you loop over values instead of indexes. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337152/finding-the-longest-alphabetical-order-substring-in-a-longer-stringer/62337352#62337352

Answer (score 0):

The most direct answer to the question you asked is "because of the -1 in the `range` in the `for` loop). It is difficult to access "previous and current" or "current and next" in a for loop like this because you always have to deal with the "edge case" of there not being a previous or a next element in your iterator.

Here is a better way of doing what you are trying to do:

```
input_string = "abcuiahduehjoahduflcpfghijklmnprstvz"

ls = ""
temp = ""
previous_c = ""

for c in input_string:
    if c >= previous_c:
        temp += c
    else:
        if len(ls) < len(temp):
            ls = temp
        temp = c
    previous_c = c

if len(ls) < len(temp):
    ls = temp

print("longest alphabetically-ordered substring is:")
print(ls)
```

I have used the same variable names as in your example. Notice how I loop over each character `c` in the `input_string`. Notice how I don't try to access previous/last characters but instead I have a `last_c` variable to hold the last seen character from the previous loop iteration. This `last_c` is initially assigned to an empty string so it is always "less than" all other characters/strings.

If you really wanted to use indexes instead (which you shouldn't) then it would look like this (very very similar):

```
input_string = "abcuiahduehjoahduflcpfghijklmnprstvz"

ls = ""
temp = ""
previous_c = ""

for i in range(len(input_string)):
    c = input_string[i]
    if c >= previous_c:
        temp += c
    else:
        if len(ls) < len(temp):
            ls = temp
        temp = c
    previous_c = c

if len(ls) < len(temp):
    ls = temp

print("longest alphabetically-ordered substring is:")
print(ls)
```